# ReportExecutionService not honoring timeout

Tags: c#, .net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, system.net.webexception

I am using .NET ReportExecutionService to render SSRS reports. We are rendering many reports in rapid fire and we are randomly getting reports that timeout. Somewhere around 1 out of 1400 reports will hang.

When I check the hanging report in ExecutionLog3, I see the report with a status of rsSuccess, and a total time of around 3s. So it looks like the report finishes but the response never gets seen by the render call, and times out after 5 minutes with the following exception:

```
    System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (1, 2655). ---> System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out.
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadBuffer(Char[] userBuffer, Int32 userOffset, Int32 desiredChars, Boolean& readToUserBuffer)
   at System.IO.StreamReader.Read(Char[] buffer, Int32 index, Int32 count)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ReadData()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseText(Int32& startPos, Int32& endPos, Int32& outOrChars)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseText()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElementContent()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReader.Read()
   at System.Xml.XmlReader.ReadElementString()
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReader1.Read12_ReportParameter(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType)
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReader1.Read17_ExecutionInfo(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType)
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReader1.Read111_SetExecutionParametersResponse()
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.ArrayOfObjectSerializer25.Deserialize(XmlSerializationReader reader)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

If anyone has any suggestions on how to prevent these timeouts I would be glad to try, but I think the easier solution for now is if I can figure out how to set a shorter timeout on the render call. If I can time out and retry the report after 30s that will still give us the performance we need.

Here is my render call. What timeout option do I need to change to make this call fail after 30s?

```
//tried setting the timeout in the constructor
var rsExec = new rsExecService.ReportExecutionService
{
       Url = string.Format("{0}{1}", url, executionServiceUrl), Timeout = 30000
};
//tried setting the timeout before calling render
rsExec.Timeout = 30 * 1000;
results = rsExec.Render(format, deviceInfo, out extension, out mimeType, out encoding, out warnings, out streamIDs);
```

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue.  I will be interested to hear how it is solved

Comment: What happens if you set the `Timeout` value to `Timeout.Infinite` (from System.Threading)? Any change?

Comment: @R.Richards Timeout.Infinite still gives the 5 minute time out. I just figured out that if I run this process with a small amount jobs, say 10, the 30s timeout works. It is only when I run this on our web server with a queue of 1000+ jobs I see the 5 min timeout. It seems that when I have more threads, the timeout is not honored

Comment: Sounds like you might have a workaround in that, smaller batches. Not sure if that is desirable, though.